# Stream video on multiple devices using python

Tags: python, opencv, flash, video-streaming

I want to stream live video from my laptop which should be accessible on multiple devices at the same time. Following is the code I found for streaming video using python flask, but it can stream video only on single device at a time. As soon as another device hits the URL the streaming on first device pauses and another one starts.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True,port=8085)
```

```
#camera.py
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg',image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

My expectation is that multiple users should be able to join the stream at the same time from their respective browsers.

Comment: I understand your goal, but what specific question do you need answered to move forward with your project?

Comment: How can multiple users access the same video stream at the same time?